# Best place for questions about Medicare from a consumer point of view

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Wondering what the best Stack Exchange sites are for US Medicare questions. For instance, "does medicare cover..."  "How is ... handled under medicare?" and the like.  A search for "medicare" seems to bring up some sites related to integrating medicare-related actions into other software, and the law site, but I'm wondering if the law site is the best place.

Answer (score 6):

If your Medicare questions can be tailored to money, [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) has a [medicare tag](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicare) (in addition to other Medicare questions without the tag).